# Using arcpy.GetParametersAsText() into Text file?

Tags: arcpy, parameters

I've just started using Python for ArcMap. I'm trying out a script that works before I put arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) into it. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? (I put the parameters on the command line).

Coding is for Icelandic letters

```
#-*-coding: cp1252 -*-

import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import os

k = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
arcpy.env.workspace = k
inFeatureClass = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

txtFile = open(os.path.join(env, "GGSkrár15.txt"), "w")
txtFile.write("Upplýsingar um skrár fyrir gagnagrunn Póst- og Fjarskiptastofnunar" + "\n")
txtFile.write("-------------------------------------" + "\n")

desc = arcpy.Describe(inFeatureClass)
desc2 =  "Skráarheiti: {} Shape: {} Gerð: {}\n".format(desc.name, desc.shapeType,
                                            desc.datasetType)
txtFile.write(desc2)

desc3 = arcpy.Describe(inFeatureClass)
desc4 = "Extent: {} Hnitakerfi: {}\n".format(desc3.extent, desc3.spatialReference.name)
txtFile.write(desc4)

field_list = arcpy.ListFields(inFeatureClass)


for field in field_list:
    line = "Dálkaheiti: {}, Gerð: {}, Fjöldi stafa leifður: {}\n".format(
         field.name, field.type, field.length)
    txtFile.write(line)

txtFile.close()
print "Script completed"
```

Comment: What happens when you use `arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)`? Does the script return an error/do nothing? Try inspecting the value and type of `k`-- what exactly is it?

Comment: @Paul `arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)` always returns a string.

Comment: You assign your input to the variable `k`, but then never reference the variable `k` in your script.

Comment: @EmilBrundage, `k` is referenced in the next line of the script. And yes, `k` will always be a string.

Comment: Whoops, missed that, sorry.

Comment: I changed the script but it always returns:"TypeError: object of type 'GPEnvironment' has no len()"

Comment: k is the workspace im setting. Its a ArcGis geodatabase and the inFeatureClass is a shapefile that I want to be described in a file:).

Answer (score 1):

There are some modifications to the code you have to make:

```
k = "D:\Lilja\SHP_f_GG\SHP_f_GG.gdb"

arcpy.env.workspace = k
inFeatureClass = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

env_folder = os.path.dirname(arcpy.env.workspace)
arcpy.AddMessage(env_folder)

txtFile = open(os.path.join(env_folder, u"GGSkrár15.txt"), "w")
arcpy.AddMessage(txtFile)
```

1) Put `r` in front of all the strings. This will let Python parse your path correctly without problems with escape characters `\t`, `\n` etc

2) You should get a parent folder for the geodatabase, this is done `k = "D:\Lilja\SHP_f_GG\SHP_f_GG.gdb"`. You want to save your file in `D:\Lilja\SHP_f_GG`.

3) Join not `env` which is a GPEnvironment object; rather join the folder path and the file name: `txtFile = open(os.path.join(env_folder, u"GGSkrár15.txt"), "w")`

4) Always add `u` in front of the strings where non-ASCII characters are used, such as `u"GGSkrár15.txt"`. This will let you preserve Unicode characters.

5) When running from ArcMap, it might be helpful to see what your variables refer to, so use `arcpy.AddMessage()` function for that.

Since you are creating env.workspace in a geodatabase, you are supposed to describe a feature class inside the geodatabase. If you are interested in describing the shapefile, your workspace should be pointed to the folder, not the geodatabase.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I will probably usually be describing shapefiles, but actually in that sample I was using a file in a geodatabase. But even though I changed that, the same error massage: " ´GPEnvironment´ has no len()" appears.

Comment: I changed the code to mach and took out the enviroment. My files that I want to describe are actually in different folders.

Comment: You cannot join paths like this: `os.path.join(env,file`. Env is an object, not the string. This is why you get `GPEnvironment´ has no len()"` error message. Please try to describe your question again, it might be hard for others to help as it's hard to see what exact problem you face. If needed, ask a new question and try to focus on a small problem.